# All available predicates in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Is it possible to get a list of all the predicates and functions that I can use from in Isabelle ?

Because more often than not it happens, that I start defining by hand a predicate that I need for a proof (like `coprime`) only to realize that it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is `find_consts` that can search the defined constants either by type or by name, similarly to `find_theorems`, e.g. `find_consts "'a list => nat"` or `find_consts name:"lim"`. Apparently, this can also find abbreviations like `coprime` (which is an abbreviation for `gcd a b = 1`).

Of course, this can only find constants that were defined in one of the theories you have actually loaded (either directly or indirectly). There is always the possibility that the concept you need has already been formalised somewhere in `~~/src/HOL/Library` or some other part of the distribution or in the AFP.

When I suspect that this is the case, I just grep the distribution or the AFP for an appropriate keyword or I ask someone who might know about it. Asking here on StackOverflow might also be a good idea to find out something like this, since there are a number of professional Isabelle users who frequent this site and who have good knowledge of what is there and what is not.

Comment: These are great tipps, thanks! But can you tell me, where exactly you found `coprime` ? Because searching for `nat => nat` didn't return the coprime. I'm also slightly confused why `find_consts` returns functions, rather than constants, as I would have expected from the naming.

Comment: Functions are also constants, just ones that have a function type. ‘Constant’ in Isabelle just means that it is some value that has been declared in the background theory, as opposed to e.g. a bound or free variable.

Comment: If anything, you should have searched for `nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool` to find `coprime`. Unfortunately, this does not work either, since coprimality is defined using the GCD, and GCD is not defined on `nat` but much more generally. The only reasonable way to find it is by name, i.e. `find_consts name:coprime`. (You could search for `'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool`, but that will return so much other stuff that you'll never find anything useful in there)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but are you sure that `find_consts name:coprime` works? Because it returns `found nothing`. Similarly, grepping through the 306 constants that `'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool` also didn't reveal any occurence of `coprime` (I'm using the latest version of Isabelle together with jEdit)

Comment: (Here's the complete MWE: `(*<*) theory Totient imports Main begin (*>*)
find_consts "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
(*<*) end (*>*)` )

Comment: This is because `gcd` and `coprime` are not part of `Main`. They are defined in `GCD`, so you either have to import `GCD` additionally or, perhaps better, `~~/src/HOL/Number_Theory/Number_Theory` for all of Isabelle's number theory library.